# Possible to change the $.post url based on an if statement?

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, .post

I apologize in advance for my ignorance, I am still really new to jquery and php.  If I am trying to do something horrid then please let me know.  That being said, here is what I am doing:

The following script is working properly, its just a small snippet from my 'createLogin.js'.

Throughout the script there are numerous calls to php files like this:

```
$.post( 'verifyUserNo.php' ,  //this is url is what I want to change
{
    No   : trimmedUserNo ,
    Name : companyName

} ).done( function( verifyUserNo ) {

            if ( verifyUserNo  == "Not a valid customer name or code" ) {

                console.log( "The Company Code Entered Is Not Authentic" ) ;

            } else
            if ( verifyUserNo == "valid" ) {

                console.log( "The Company Code Entered Is Authentic" ) ;


             $.post( 'compareUserName.php' ,   //This post will be the same 
                                               //regardless of user level.
             {
                 newName : desiredName

             } ).done( function( data ) {

                 if (data == "taken") { alert('Choose another username') ;}
                 else if (data == "available") {

                     $.post( 'removeUserNo.php'   //This one needs
                                                  //to change as well
```

Though its working as it is, I am adding a condition where the type of user being created is calculated by a number pulled from my database earlier in the script.  i.e.

```
var usrLevel = 2  //could is dynamically set to any int greater than 0 and less than 5.
```

Now, if `usrLevel == 2`  then the script above is what i want to execute.  However,

if `usrLevel == X //where x is not 2` I want to change

`$.post( 'verifyUserNo.php'`  to  `$.post( 'verifyUserAth.php'` because the data for users with a level or 3 is stored in a separate table on my db than if their level is 2.

Without nesting the rest of my script inside an if/else statement.  I am trying to change the above url to direct to a different php file for each value of `usrLevel` so essentially 4 possibilities.

### Solved by tic - see below

Comment: `$.post( usrLevel  == 2 ? 'verifyUserNo.php'  : 'verifyUserAth.php', {}...` - Just use the ternary operator

Comment: @Arun P Johny   Thanks, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = (usrLevel === 2) ? 'verifyUserNo.php' : 'verifyUserAth.php';
var data = { dataIwantToSend: 3 };
$.post(url, data, function(response) {
   //Do this when complete
});
```

**Edit:**

User asks to use ternary with 4 possibilities. It sure is:

```
var url = (x === 1) ? 'myurl4' : (x === 2) ? 'myurl3' : (x === 3) ? 'myurl3' : 'myurl4';
```

Although it gets harder to read at this point, and switch case may be better as you can throw an error legibly if none of the cases are matched.

```
var url = null;
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        url = 'myurl4';
        break;
    case 2:
        url = 'myurl3';
        break;
    case 3:
        url = 'myurl2';
        break;
    case 4:
        url = 'myurl1';
        break;
    default:
        throw 'My error';
}
```

or just a simple if/else if/else

Comment: thanks tic, is it possibly to use the ternary operator for var url but with 4 possibilities?